# In one Linq Query get back data from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have 3 tables:

1. sessions - This store information about trainings
2. xref_session_faculty - This cross references the trainings and the teacher
3. user - list of all teachers

In one(or more) LINQ query i want to get all the sessions and for each session the teachers that will be conducting the training. Each session can have zero or more teachers in the DB.

```
sessions = db.sessions
.Where(x => x.seminar_id == seminarId)
.ToList()
.Select((x, i) => new fees
{
    id = x.id,
    sessionTitle = x.title,

    teacherNames = "By:" + String.Join(",",
            x.xref_session_faculty.ToList()
            .Select(q => db.users
                .Where(m => m.id == q.user_id)
                .Select(t => t.firstName).ToList()
            )
    )
})
.ToList();
```

With this the teacherNames prints out `By:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`.

WHat is the right query format here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 teacherNames = "By:" + String.Join(",",
        x.xref_session_faculty.ToList()
        .Select(q => db.users
            .Where(m => m.id == q.user_id)
            .Select(t => t.firstName).FirstOrDefault()
        )
)
```

you need to change ToList to FirstOrDefault function to get correct result

Answer (score 0):

`private var sessions = (from session in db.sessions.Where(x => x.seminar_id == seminarId)
            select new
            {
                id = session.id,
                sessionTitle = session.title,
                teacherNames = (from faculty in db.xref_session_faculty.
                    where (x => x.session_id == session.id)
                    join us in db.uses on faculty.user_id equals us.user_id
                    select new
                    {
                        us.firstName,
                        other_field_names
                    })
            });`